# How to create custom kafka authorizer and use it for local kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to create custom authorizer for kafka.
Can someone provide example on how I can implement org.apache.kafka.server.authorizer.Authorizer interface

implementation of org.apache.kafka.server.authorizer.Authorizer interface

Comment: can you explain what is the authorizer for ? for exemple is it for such as creating topics, deleting topics or something else .

Comment: This is for all actions, create, delete, write read on topics

Answer (score 0):

please note that i am working with Springboot 2.7 and java 11 (kafka 2.8)

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.Configurable;
import org.apache.kafka.common.Endpoint;
import org.apache.kafka.common.acl.AclBinding;
import org.apache.kafka.common.acl.AclBindingFilter;
import org.apache.kafka.server.authorizer.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

public class MyAuthorizer implements Authorizer, Configurable {


//you should add your own logic for the following methods  and not return 
//null for exemple :
// return Collections.singletonList(AuthorizationResult.ALLOWED);




@Override
public Map<Endpoint, ? extends CompletionStage<Void>> 
start(AuthorizerServerInfo authorizerServerInfo) {
    return null;

}

@Override
 public List<AuthorizationResult> authorize(AuthorizableRequestContext 
authorizableRequestContext, List<Action> list) {
 return null ; }    }

@Override
public List<? extends CompletionStage<AclCreateResult>> createAcls(AuthorizableRequestContext authorizableRequestContext, List<AclBinding> list) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<? extends CompletionStage<AclDeleteResult>> deleteAcls(AuthorizableRequestContext authorizableRequestContext, List<AclBindingFilter> list) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Iterable<AclBinding> acls(AclBindingFilter aclBindingFilter) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {

}

@Override
public void configure(Map<String, ?> map) {

}
```